# Uploaded file is always overwitten

Tags: php, file-upload

I have this php code that uploads a photo from the iPhone into this directory. The problem I have is that each time a photo is uploaded it overwrites the previous one. How can I get it so all the images are stored?

```
<?php
$name = "image";
$path = "uploaded/".$name.".jpg";
$output = "{\"response\":\"false\"}";   
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $path)) {
     $output = "{\"response\":\"true\"}";
}
echo $output;
?>
```

Comment: Use `sha1_file()` or `md5_file()` as a filename http://php.net/manual/en/function.sha1-file.php http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5-file.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you upload a file, you move it to the same directory with the same name.

There are many things that you can do the simplest being.

```
// produces something like image-1415317895-545c0987ce42c5
$name = "image-" . uniqid(time() . "-");
```

You should also look into verifying that the uploaded file is indeed an image.

```
$info = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']); 

if (is_array($info) && array_key_exists('mime', $info) && $info['mime'] === 'image/jpeg') {
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $path);
}
```

Resources:

[**uniqid()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php)
[**time()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php)
[**getimagesize()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php)

Comment: That worked. Thank you so much. If you don't mind I would like to ask you another question. Now that the files are being stored how can I get to view them in my browser? I want to create a very simple html page that just displays the photos. Any thoughts there? When I type the actual php file address in my browser I get this. {"response":"false"} When I want it to show the files in that folder

Comment: @user2442173 you're welcome. To answer this question there are so many specifics that are unknown. For example: Are the uploaded files meant to be only visible to the uploaded? Shared with others? Are you using a database? Are there user accounts? ... (the list goes on and on) I suggest that you try a few things yourself based on the requirements (of witch I know nothing about) of your application. If you are still having problems, ask another question. :)

Comment: Thanks. I will ask another question but you were so fast to respond with the perfect answer I thought I would ask you. Basically I want anyone to go to the webpage and see the photos that are uploaded from the application. I'm not using a database or anything fancy. That simple PHP script uploaded the photos to the folder. I just need an html code that will display them. I'm an iOS developer but have no real PHP knowledge

Answer (score -1):

**They're overridden because they have the same name.**

In order to tackle this we would have to make every name unique, I think the best way to do this is like this:

```
$name = "image_" . sha1 (openssl_random_pseudo_bytes (100));
```

This way you are absolutely sure the name will be unique.

Should it be the case that OpenSSL is not installed then `mt_random ()` is a great alternative.

```
$name = "image_" . sha1 (mt_random (0, 1000000));
```

Comment: openssl is not always installed. http://php.net/manual/en/openssl.requirements.php

Comment: @robbmj Of course, that however does not take away that it is a very solid way of generating a random file name.
If someone was to stay away from OpenSSL then there's always [mt_random()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) Allow me to edit my answer.